# Python decorator for function completion

Tags: python

Is it possible to develop a decorator to determine if a function successfully completed without crashing ? Something like the decorator below but it must detect if the function ran successfully.

```
def functionStartDecorator():
    print("Function has started")
    def decoratorWrapper(functionToBeDecorated):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            #Todo log function has run
            return functionToBeDecorated(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decoratorWrapper
```

Comment: Maybe you could wrap the call to `functiontoBeDecorated` into `try/except` and print some log message or do some other standard error handling code in the except clause. _If_ that's what you meant with "ran successfully"...

Comment: Also, note that right now, `"Function has started"` is not printed when the function starts, but when it is decorated.

Comment: Thanks. So when does the function really start ? and end in this decorator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in comments, simplest would be to wrap your function in a try/except. If your function returns nothing and simply operate by side-effect, it should be straightforward to have the decorated function *return* the status of that function run:

```
def tryfn(f):
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            f(*args, **kwargs)
            return 'Ran successfully'
        except Exception as e:
            return 'Error: {}'.format(e)
    return decorated
```

You can then tweak the exact return type of decorated: maybe return a boolean, maybe append the status of the function to the return of `f`, maybe log things... The core principle will probably still be around a `try/except` within the decorated function. For instance, if you want to return both your return value (or `None` if it failed) and whether this was a success:

```
def tryfn(f):
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            res = f(*args, **kwargs)
            return True, res
        except:
            return False, None
    return decorated
```

Note that in this case, you're **losing** the information about the exact error, so you might want to expand the return to include success, failure, error, etc... that becomes a trade-off between convenience and completeness, which will depend on your exact problem.

Comment: Problem is my function does return somthing

Comment: Then you can return both the return value (or `None` in case of a failure) a la Go:
`try:
    res = f(*args, **kwargs)
    return True, res
except:
    return False, None
`
or something along these lines; Edited the answer to include that.

Comment: The decorated function should generally return the same values as the non-decorated function, otherwise you have to change all the code that's using that function. Better just log/print the error and/or re-raise the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this. Do you see any issues with this code ?

```
def functionStartDecorator():
    def decoratorWrapper(functionToBeDecorated):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                print("Function has started")
                result=functionToBeDecorated(*args, **kwargs)
                print("Function has complete")
                return result
            except:
                print ("Function failed")
        return wrapper
    return decoratorWrapper  

@functionStartDecorator()
def simplefunc():
    return "somthing"
```